# Why don't my disabling commands work in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

My code is 140 lines long, but it is based on some of this:

```
  $('oracle').onchange = disablefield;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xjLknxp8/

I'm trying to only allow someone to type in one field with that radio button selected...

Comment: That's not how you change attributes in jquery.  First, your selector: do you really have a tag called `oracle`? - Then, the event should be of the form `$(selector).on('change', function(){...});` - Lastly, attribute values are changed like this `$(selector).attr('attrName', 'attrValue');`

Comment: ahh, you're right - oracle and others are actually ID's so I've prepended those with a hash #. I tried the suggestion below to use 'prop('disabled',true);' but no luck so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just adjusted your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wmtps9b/) with following shorter version:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    disableOther(this.id);
  });
});

function disableOther(item){
    $(".form-body input[type='text']").each(function(){
      $(this).removeAttr('disabled').val("");
    });   
    $("input[type='radio']").not("#" + item).closest("tr")
                            .find("input[type='text']").each(function(){
      $(this).prop('disabled',true);
    });   
}
```

Instead of disabling every single input field for each radio button value, just disable all input fields that are in a `tr` that does not contain the clicked radio button and remove the `disable` attribute for all text input fields before setting it to `disabled` for the two other rows.

Comment: Thanks - I knew there was a more simple way to look at the problem, very nice.

Comment: One thing I found is that before any radio button is checked, you can enter all fields.... In my HTML I tried adding checked="true" but it didn't get caught by the script. Can I just target the selector and mark it checked in the same script?

Comment: @JacobIRR You mean you want to disable all input fields and only enable the appropriate fields when a radio button is clicked? Just in case, this could be done like in this adjusted Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c0aL8cem/

Comment: Got it!     $("input[type='text']").prop('disabled', true);
--thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This template will do it:

```
 $('input[name=bill_code1_1]').prop('disabled',true);
```

Rather than what you had, which was

```
 $('input[name=bill_code1_1]').disabled=true;
```

It's DOMObject.disabled = true or $Selector.prop('disabled',true);
You were using a selector as if it was a DOM object.

Comment: I realized I had no # before my id's.. I implemented your solution with no luck so far. I'm not getting any console errors or errors in JSHINT. still playing with it.

Comment: I put it to the test before posting. I'll post up a snippet shortly and take another look at your fiddle.

Comment: Here is the second iteration with your and ochi's fix:  http://jsfiddle.net/xjLknxp8/2/

Comment: Looks like matthias_h provided a great solution.
Just the same, I've updated this fiddle to fix a few other issues that were keeping it from working - how the event handlers were being registered and how the checked states were being evaluated in the if statements.
http://jsfiddle.net/xjLknxp8/3/